Can I find out why CSP rejected a specific resource?
I am working on creating Content-Security-Protocol headers.  I have a directive that is rejecting a resource.  However, my research indicates it should not.  Is there a way to find out the details of why the CSP header is rejecting the resource.
The directive definition is "form-action 'self';".
The action being taken is a redirect to the same page making the redirect.
To be clear, the details of the action are that a Javascipt handler for a Button is redirecting to a page (in the same domain).  That page is then redirecting back to the original page.  The only code being evaluated is the 'if' statements to determine where to redirect.

The dev tools console should show CSP violations, but if there's redirects involved you'll want to enable "preserve log" so that the console isn't cleared along the way. However, the issue is because form-action behavior regarding redirects is inconsistently implemented in diff browsers as there a disagreements on how it should behave. See the notification on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/form-action

Apparently you can work around this by adding the explicit URL that is redirected to as an additional argument on form-action (as well as self)

I use Developer Tools.  It does not provided enough detail about why the resource request violated the directive.  I know that different browsers handle this differently.  We need to support Chrome, which doesn't work.  I have tried adding the specific URL in various forms (domain only, full URL).  Nothing I have tried works.  I looked at the CSP specification and there are several checks made when processing the form-action directive.  I'm trying find a way to determine which specific check is causing the failure.

Yeh you are out of luck I think on that unless you have chrome itself under debug conditions :(
